# Convert double precision number to rational fraction plus exponent

Tags: arithmetic, computer-science, floating-point

I have a double precision quantity (either pixels per cm or pixels per inch)
that gets converted into pixels per meter. I then need to convert this number
into a rational fraction, with numerator and denominator as unsigned shorts, and exponent of signed byte.

I realize this is an ill-posed problem, but I am looking for the best way of doing this conversion.

Thanks.

Comment: Multiply by $100$ or $\frac{100}{2.54}$.  Extract the exponent and then consider something like continued fraction approximations until you exceed the capacity of your shorts

Comment: [This](http://www.willamette.edu/~mjaneba/help/frac.html) may be of interest to you

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot. Continued fractions ftw.

Comment: I found this on stack overflow:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637967/algorithm-challenge-generate-continued-fractions-for-a-float#4641598